# Is there a simple way how a custom UITableViewCell can have the same edges as a standard UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with static content that has a UIStackView as the single child view of the content view. I would like the UIStackView to use the same horizontal margins/insets as the standard UITableViewCell built into UIKit, across all iOS versions beginning with iOS 9 (my minimum deployment target) down to the current iOS 14, and on both iPhone and iPad devices.

I naively started with adding constraints that attach the UIStackView's leading/trailing anchors to the content view's `readableContentGuide`. I don't like Interface Builder so this is how my code looks like:

```
UIStackView stackView = [...]
[stackView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[stackView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
```

This works pretty well, except in some scenarios (1) where the standard UITableViewCell does **not** use `readableContentGuide`, so mixing the standard cells with my custom cells looks bad because their edges do not align. Here you see 4 custom cells with one standard cell at the top and at the bottom:

[image]

(1) It happens in these scenarios:

- On iPhone devices with a notch, when the device is held in Landscape orientation
- On iPad devices, both in Portrait and Landscape orientation

I have tried using `layoutMarginsGuide` instead of `readableContentGuide`, but this results in many constraint errors ("Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." in Xcode's debug output). I have also tried setting

```
self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = YES;
```

in table views that use my custom cell, and this works inasmuch as the standard cells now have their edges in the same place as my custom cells. But I don't like the workaround, first because it means I have to have special set up for each and every table view that wants to use my custom cell, and second because it unnecessarily reduces the width available for data display.

It seems I am missing something. Is there a simple, standard way how one can layout the content of a custom UITableViewCell, using layout guides, so that the custom cell content's edges are in the same place as a standard cell's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the cell's `.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide`:

```
UILayoutGuide *g = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide;

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

    [stackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor],
    [stackView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor],
    [stackView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor],
    [stackView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor],

]];
```

If that gives you "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" messages but the layout looks correct - which is common when using stack views in cells - you can either ignore the messages or give the bottom anchor less-than-required priority:

```
UILayoutGuide *g = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide;

NSLayoutConstraint *c = [stackView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor];
c.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

    [stackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor],
    [stackView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor],
    [stackView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor],
    
    c,
    
]];
```

Comment: You're right, of course, `layoutMarginsGuide` is the simple one-stop solution I was looking for. The "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" message was generated because I had a custom constraint (i.e. not one made by UIStackView) which in hindsight was embarassingly wrong.